# GitHub Actions - share services across jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-actions

I would like to know how I can share service containers between jobs in GitHub Actions. With this workflow currently the containers get destroyed after the `build` step.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  RAILS_ENV: test
  RACK_ENV: test
  RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres15
  POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST: localhost

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Initialize Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Setup Rails
        run: bin/setup
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:15.1-alpine
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{ env.POSTGRES_USERNAME }}
        # needed because the postgres container does not provide a healthcheck
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready 
          --health-interval 10s 
          --health-timeout 5s 
          --health-retries 5

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ build ]
    steps:
      - name: Lint Ruby
        run: bundle exec rubocop
      - name: Run tests
        run: bin/rails test:all

  coverage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ build, test ]
    steps:
      - uses: joshmfrankel/simplecov-check-action@main
        with:
          minimum_suite_coverage: 98
          minimum_file_coverage: 90
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          check_job_name: coverage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, you cannot share service containers across jobs.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers

> You can configure service containers for each job in a workflow. GitHub creates a fresh Docker container for each service configured in the workflow, and destroys the service container when the job completes. Steps in a job can communicate with all service containers that are part of the same job. However, you cannot create and use service containers inside a composite action.